# How to capture missing URLs (Error 404) using PHP?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my webserver, I have created a **.htaccess** file with the following lines to redirect the wrong/missing URLs (Error 404), to the php file **not_found.php**. It works fine.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://myserver.edu.in/not_found.php
```

Can I able to capture list of wrong/missing URLs into a text file (or) display the wrong/missing URL in the error page **not_found.php** itself?

I tried the PHP variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in the **not_found.php** file to capture the wrong/missing URLs. Now I have two issues.

1. Since I have used the full URL of the error page in **.htaccess**, it fails. If I change it to `ErrorDocument 404 /not_found.php`. It works fine only inside the same directory.
2. In the **not_found.php** file, I have used `include_once` function to include header, footer, images, and scripts. So, If I change the **.htaccess** to `ErrorDocument 404 /not_found.php`, the error page **not_found.php** does not display properly in the different directory.

   For example, http://myserver.edu.in/xxx/trial.php

   In this case, I used full URL for images and scripts. But, not able to use full URL for PHP files using `include_once` function.

Can anybody suggest some better ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: About the second issue, can you explain a bit further? `does not display properly in the different directory` I really have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois In second issue, the error page does not display the included files while in other directories.

Comment: Apache already logs all 404 errors to it's own logs. You would probably be better off parsing this log or finding a program that handles this.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Not true. If you put a php script as the 404 error document, it runs that script just fine. We use this to redirect all pages, including 404 errors to a login form on a site that requires login for every page you load.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Ah yes you are right, I missed that part of the question obviously. Time for a coffe obviously

Comment: @ak-SE: In that case it is the issue with your include path not .htaccess

Comment: @anubhava: We can't able to fix permanent path for include files using include_once function, for unknown directory. For example, http://myserver.edu.in/xxx/yyyy/trial.php

Answer (score 0):

With the ErrorDocument directive, Apache also sets some special environment variables, for example:

```
REDIRECT_URL
REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING
```

These should be available if (as you already noticed) the error document does not have a path starting with http. Thus, you can store the not found requests in your database or some text file.

However, `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` is available as well, I am using it in a similar case to redirect requests to another domain, if the file is not on that specific server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the missing urls, or even better, you could use PHP to include the not_found.php file. The problem with redirecting that that search engines will think that the directory /not_found.php cannot be found and will think that the redirected url is just being redirected.

Example:

```
<?php
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found", true, 404);
include("notFound.php");
?>
```

EDIT: If you are using this in the event of a file not existing on the actual server you will need to rewrite.